# chrome extension - randomly reloading thus loosing all state variables

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Helllo all

I'm strugling to figure out why my background.js script is randomly reloaded in browser if I reload, open, close tabs.
The problem is that background script holds some state variables and these get lost if script/extension is reloaded.
What I tried so far:

1. Opening developer console for script worker, does not produce this problem.
2. I tried to use local storage to store state variables, but not luck. When script is reloaded local storage value is gone.
3. I do not reload extension nor change background scripts in any way while testing

**[EDIT]**
https://www.dropchop.com/test.zip OR https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtisv8c8pgxnu7z/test.zip?dl=0
Here is test extension. Install it unpacked. Open service worker developer console. Copy paste time from console. Close dev console. Open,close,refresh 10 or more tabs, pages. Reopen service worker developer console. Check time. In my case it's not the same, so that means it was reloaded.

Using Chrome on Linux: Version 97.0.4692.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Don't have any other ideas and can't find any help online about it, so I'll appreciate it here

Regards

Armando

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) we can only guess, which is a waste of your time and ours.

Comment: I've edited the question ;)

Comment: That site doesn't open and you must include all relevant code inside the question on StackOverflow. It sounds like you're using ManifestV3 in which case the behavior is intentional, see [this documentation article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/).

Comment: bummer .. I've read the docs now .. service worker script gets reloaded .. but I put everything into local storage and load it if this happens but data is gone ... as if realoding cleans local storage ...

Comment: It means your code is incorrect or there's a bug in Chrome. You need to show the code in the question, not on an external site.

Comment: There were 2 problems. First me not knowing service worker lifecycle and second I had a typo in my code when storing state into local storage.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) I've managed to figure this one out.

1. service workers in manifest v3 are not stateful so they get destroyed and recreated and that's how state variables get lost
2. Store state variables in local storage but beware because, when you get something from local storage you get an object in result. Like object with your key in it
   `{ "yourKey" : {... your data ....}}`